How to extend @nestjs/schematics
I would like to do as same as the @nestjs/cli is doing with it's own schematics but by replacing some of them by my own code.
I didn't found any documentation or help and I struggle to understand how to make it work.
What are the files which are needed, how to make it work please ?
EDIT
What is the process to implement custom schematics using @nestjs/cli ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
